# Rails json response that includes javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I have an application that responds to .json (json format). I also have to build a bookmarklet that makes a div on the page where you execute it. This bookmarklet makes a request to the application and the application should respond with a json object that contains the javascript. Let's say this is all the javascript is:

```
function selectElementContents()
{
  el = document.getElementById('quicklink_value')
  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        // IE
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.select();
        textRange.execCommand("Copy");
    }
  else if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        // non-IE
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        var range = document.createRange();
        try {
        var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
        var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
      }
    }
}
content = "<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'events/bookmarklet').html_safe) %>";
_tp_bookmarklet(content);
```

As you can see I also have a partial that needs to be rendered inside a variable named content.

```
def bookmarklet
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json
    end
  end
```

This is the action that is being called by the bookmarklet. How can I put the javascript(with the content variable that contains the rendered partial in it) as the json response?
I can provide any additional info that is needed.

Comment: You can do it with simply `@content = escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'events/bookmarklet').html_safe)` and then `format.json {content: @content}` and in you front end you could  you can get the `json` response and response will have your html..

Comment: Missing partial events/_bookmarklet it doesn't seem to find the partial ... any idea ?

Comment: Do you have the partial view in the view folder??

Comment: Yes, I do. Well that's my problem now, as I said you should post it as the answer so I can check it.

Comment: It doesn't feel right.. can you share your other problem.. so that I can have a look into it?

Comment: At first I wanted to send a string in a json response but that is not a standard way that an API should work. Now I moved the HTML in my bookmarklet and the json just gives me responses which I use to make a decision. But the problem was that render is just for views , if you want to make the html a string you must use the render_to_string method :D

Comment: Thanks dude.. I didn't know it.. :).. I'll have a look into this method.. and for the part of having html.. and json api.. I have used angular with rails.. in not a very elegant way but works very good..

Comment: Yes that's what my application uses also. But a bookmarklet is a javascript that makes a request to my server , and since it is an api , I have to render a json response :d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with simply

```
@content = escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'events/bookmarklet').html_safe)
```

and then

```
format.json {content: @content}
```

and in you front end you could you can get the json response and response will have your html.

another way is to to do is to directly render the partial/template and sen it off as a json object... but that will work when you have a way to cater the controller variables in the partial... like if you are using controller variables either instance or local you should take care of those.

```
format.json { content: escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'events/bookmarklet').html_safe) }
```

or what you can do is a create a `method` may be private to render out your partial like

```
def blahblah (params...)
    escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'events/bookmarklet').html_safe)
end
........
format.json {content: blahblah(params)}
```